# Angular Material components are not rendered in Universal Application

Tags: angular-material, angular-universal

I have an existing Angular application which I am now rendering with Angular Universal severside. The application uses Angular material. Unfortunately, the styling of the material components is not rendering correctly on the node server. Does anyone have any idea what this could be due to?

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: "serverApp" }),
  NoopAnimationsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  MaterialModule,
],
```

**app.server.module.ts**

```
imports: [AppModule, ServerModule],
```

**Browser**

[image: Browser]

**Server**

[image: Universal]

Answer (score 0):

check on your browser development tool F12 to see if there are other errors. I bet you there are and that will give you the hint to what is going on.

Comment: The Console is "clean".

Comment: refresh when you are accessing it on server.

Comment: also are you using the same browser

Comment: there are "no issues" on refreshing the page. i use Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) snap (64-bit).

Comment: Chromium Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

Comment: do you miss any css files? look into source see if anything needs to be included is included in your local that is not in your deployed package. Also, can you run these in local machine outside from running it from your IDE?

Comment: Could it be that your server is restricting your external reference  if you have any?

Comment: I have found the problem. It was neither Angular, nor Universal, nor Material. It was simply a cookie preventing my modal dialog from loading completely.

Comment: And you didn't get an error in the console?